# Concurrently running memory test (such as memtest) and also doing other things on the computer?

Tags: memory

May I know if it is possible to run memory test and doing other things at the same time on a single computer?

From my understanding, if we run memory test, we can't do other things - do correct me if I have misunderstand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the memory test should be able to access whole memory, you can't (memtest86 eg.) our shouldn't (memtest for windows) do any other stuff in parallel because you cannot test otherwise used areas of RAM.

Using memtest for windows is discouraged anyhow as the parts of memory windows has allocated to itself and background service are not available for memtest.

Operating systems do not allow processes to claim special areas of memory, so memtest software has to claim all of it at once.

Comment: So, my understanding is right as there are no memory test software that is capable of doing memory test parallel with other things on a single computer. Thanks Jens.

Comment: Yes that's correct, there are none, as no operating system allows processes to claim special areas of the memory which it formerly didn't test, so it has to claim all of it. (Updated my answer.)